# SELECT query, LIMIT 1 for one column, but, not the rest

Tags: php, mysql

Can I LIMIT 1 for one specific column but not the rest?  I have two tables.  One with info and one with images.  For as many images there are, that many info queries are run.  So,  it will be 5 images and 5 of the same title.  How can I LIMIT 1 title, and LIMIT 3 images?

```
$query = mysql_query("
                     SELECT `$category`.title AS title,
                     page_images.image_loc AS images
                     FROM `$category`, page_images
                     WHERE `$category`.title = page_images.title
                    ");

            while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

                $title  = $fetch['title'];              
                $images = $fetch['images'];

                echo '<b>'.$title.'</b><br />';
                echo '<a href="http://localhost/'.$images.'">
                        <img src="http://localhost/'.$images.'" height="80" width="80" />
                      </a>';

                }
```

Comment: Can you please explain it in more detail, its confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can group by title and collect image locations using GROUP_CONCAT. and then you can explode the collected locations to an array. and print all the images.

here what i mean

```
$query = mysql_query( "
SELECT
     title AS title
    ,GROUP_CONCAT( i.image_loc ) AS images
FROM
    `$category` c
    JOIN page_images i USING( title )
GROUP BY
    title
" );

while( $fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
    $title  = $fetch[ 'title' ];              
    $images = explode( ',', $fetch[ 'images' ] );

    echo '<b>' . $title . '</b><br />';
    foreach( $images as $image ) {
        echo '<a href="http://localhost/'.$image.'">
            <img src="http://localhost/'.$image.'" height="80" width="80" />
        </a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats awesome!  Can, I control the number images?  It outputs all the images saved that match the info.

Comment: I modified a break in the foreach statement to make it limit images.

Comment: yes you can limit the images. there is two ways to archieve this. first, in php you can use for instead of foreach. second way, in sql, as a workaround, you can limit the collection using SUBSTRING_INDEX function, like this: SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( i.image_loc ), ',', 10 ) which means get the string from beginning to 10th comma.

Comment: Not to overextend this, but how could I put: "AND type LIKE '%$type%'" on the JOIN?

Comment: you can add a WHERE clause and write all conditions there. also, you can change JOIN operator from USING to ON, if you do so you also need to give table aliases to duplicate fields. in this example you need to  state the table alias to title fields.

Answer (score 1):

Would a group by work here?

```
SELECT `$category`.title AS title,
    page_images.image_loc AS images
FROM    `$category`, page_images
WHERE   `$category`.title = page_images.title
GROUP BY title, images
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: That limits 3 images of the same page.  It also duplicates the title for each one.  GROUP BY `$category`.title LIMIT works, but only outputs one image.  I'm trying to get that effect, but with 3 or more images.

Comment: I think in this case then it makes sense to run to create a stored routine ... and use mysqli's multi-query.  Also, how big is your resultset?

Comment: Any where from 3 to 20 images.  I haven't researched those.  I look into that though.